# Detecting AiGeneratedText with CopyLeaks API doesn't return AI detection results in the final report

Tags: plagiarism-detection, copyleaks-api

I have integrated with CoopyLeaks, and liked the feature to check if text was written by AI.
However, after following the documentation, the results don't return any information regarding this aspect of the scan. Neither the generated PDF or the json object of details. This is the relevant part of the `properties` config:

```
properties: {
        aiGeneratedText: {
          detect: true,
        },
        action: 0, //0 : Scan ASAP, 1 : Check-Credits, 2 : Index Only in CopyLeaks Database.
        //scanMethodAlgorithm
        //0:MaximumCoverage: prioritize higher similarity score.
        //1: MaximumResults: prioritize finding more sources.
        scanMethodAlgorithm: 1,
        cheatDetection: true,
        }
```

- Other parts of the report are generated successfully.
- Worth mentioning that contacting the old `v2` version directly only for AI detection works, as documented in their link [here](https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/writer-detector). However, I'm trying to do it in the `v3` scan api, as mentioned by them as well according to this image:

[image]

Thank you for your time, and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, Copyleaks provide two options to consume AI Content Detection services:

- If you planning to make [Plagiarism Checker API](https://copyleaks.com/api) beside AI content detection scan, you need to use the Plagiarism Checker API and turn on the `properties.aiGeneratedText.detect` flag. Once Copyleaks will detect AI content on your submitted text, you will be notified about the incident on the [Completed Webhook](https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/webhooks/completed) under the section `notifications.alerts`. *If the submitted text will be found as human text, no alert will be created.*
- If you aiming to use the [AI Content Detection API](https://copyleaks.com/ai-content-detector-api) without plagiarism check, than you will have to use the [Writer Detector API](https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/writer-detector).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The `properties.aiGeneratedText.detect` is added to the request properties. However, the same text is 96% suspected to be generated by AI using the AI detection without plagiarism check. But when using the same text in plagiarism with AI flag enabled, no results about AI are returned.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad Require a better check. Recommend to contact the support https://help.copyleaks.com/kb-tickets/new

Comment: Thank yo so much, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sharing an alternative in case anyone else comes across this as well - https://sapling.ai/docs/api/detector/#sample-code should be pretty straightforward to get up and running.

```
curl -X POST https://api.sapling.ai/api/v1/aidetect \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"key":"<api-key>", "text":"This is sample text."}'
```

The docs have sample code for curl, javascript and python, including an HTML/ javascript SDK that can be directly integrated into your website as well.

```
<script src="https://sapling.ai/static/js/sapling-sdk-v1.0.5.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Sapling.init({
    autocomplete: true,
    mode: 'dev',
    key: 'API_DEV_TEST_KEY_SAPLING',
  });

  const contenteditable = document.getElementById('elem1');
  Sapling.observe(contenteditable);

  const aiDetectButton = document.getElementById('ai-detect-button');
  aiDetectButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    Sapling.checkOnce(contenteditable, {aiDetect: true});
  });
</script>
```

Here elem1 is your contenteditable/ text area and ai-detect-button is your button to trigger the check.