# Returned properties for AI detected text

Tags: plagiarism-detection, copyleaks-api

Please provide an example of the returned object for the AI generated text.

I'm providing some text to scan using the `/v3/scans/submit/file/{scanId}` endpoint with the `properties.aiGeneratedText.detect` flag enabled.

I was expecting to receive an example object in the sandbox webhook completed body, under the `notifications.alerts` section, as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75207188/11258206) comment.

However the received section is an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "sandbox" mode is not simulating a situation where Copyleaks detect AI content. If order to see it live, you will need to do a full check.

Once Copyleaks will execute AI detection check, the results will looks like the response of [this method](https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/writer-detector/check). Example:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "classification": 2,
      "probability": 1,
      "matches": [
        {
          "text": {
            "chars": {
              "starts": [
                0
              ],
              "lengths": [
                1509
              ]
            },
            "words": {
              "starts": [
                0
              ],
              "lengths": [
                221
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "summary": {
    "human": 0,
    "ai": 1
  },
  "scannedDocument": {
    "scanId": "check",
    "totalWords": 221,
    "totalExcluded": 0,
    "actualCredits": 1,
    "expectedCredits": 1,
    "creationTime": "2023-01-10T10:07:58.9459512Z"
  }
}
```

This will be placed under the `notifications.alerts` field.